# During onHover, how to make HTML dropdown elements adopt a new background color that is unique for each dropdown element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible onHover to make HTML dropdown elements adopt a new background color that is unique for each dropdown element?

Take the following example:

```
<select>
<option value="China">
<option value="Holland">
<option value="France">
</select>
```

**I know that you can alter styling according to an attribute's value using CSS3 attribute selectors**, in the browsers that support them:

```
option[value="China"] 
{
    background: red;
}

option[value="Holland"] 
{
    background: orange;
}

option[value="France"] 
{
    background: blue;
}
```

**But this would change their default color.** I don't want to do that. *I want all of these elements to retain their default background color of white in their resting state.*

**`I only want the dropdown element to adopt its unique color on hovering over that element in the dropdown.`**

So, for example, **on hovering over the "China" element, I would like China to have a red background color, and Holland and France would retain their white background color until they are hovered over** - at which point Holland would become orange and France would blue.

Is this possible with CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Select dropdowns by default use a dark blue on hover (in Windows at least).  Am I right in thinking this is the colour you want to change? (i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/kJ7kP/)

Comment: I answered a question just like this yesterday. Class homework?

Comment: @John Catterfield: Yes, correct. Whatever the default happens to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, *especially* not cross-browser, the `<select>` element is notoriously unstyle-able.  You can do a complete `<select>` replacement with a number of jQuery plugins, but you can't do this with raw CSS on the original `<select>` element.

Here are some [examples](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) of [replacements](http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/).